# Eliminar las vocales de un string en Javascript

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

Hola estaba haciendo una funcion que elimine todas las vocales de un string me funciona bien cuando lo hago para una letra.. asi:

```
function eliminarVocal(str) {
    var resultado = str.replace(/a/g, '');

    return resultado
}
```

si hago multiples .replace(/vocal/g, '') me funcionaria pero estaba pensando algo mas optimo, en eliminar todas las letras especificadas en un arreglo o algo por el estilo y no me funciona.. Como pudiera hacerlo.. Gracias

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Estabas muy cerca, aunque no necesitas un arreglo, con una expresión regular sencilla lo resuelves, ojo solo con las que no tiene tildes para este ejemplo.

```js
function eliminarVocales(str) {
    let resultado = str.replace(/[aeiou]/g, '')
    return resultado
}
  
  var text = "Hola Prueba de Replace y/o Javascript";
  const a = eliminarVocales(text);
  console.log(a);
```

Esta simple expresión regular `[aeiou]` establecida como global, combinada con la función `replace` busca todos los caracteres indicados en los corchetes y los reemplaza por un carácter vacío.

Para utilizarlo con todas las vocales inclusive las acentuadas, mayúsculas;

```
/[aáAÁeéEÉiíIÍoOóÓuúÚ]/g
```

```js
function eliminarVocales(str) {
    let resultado = str.replace(/[aáAÁeéEÉiíIÍoOóÓuúUÚ]/g, '')
    return resultado
}
  
  var text = "Holá PruebA de REplacé y/o JÁvascrípt";
  const a = eliminarVocales(text);
  console.log(a);
```

Comment: La solución óptima. Faltarían las mayúsculas sin tilde o agregar `i`.

Comment: @Emeeus Buena observación.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Albert... habia probado con el /aeiou/ y varias cosas mas y nunca probe los corchetes

Comment: Un placer servirte @IsraelGonzález